# How to access web services with ajax on crm 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I get values using http get method in mypage.aspx page.This page's path is under ISV/Web/mypage.aspx.How can I access and get response this asp page from onload()

Using ajax or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to do an AJAX request, somewhere along the lines of

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://YOURSERVER/mypage.aspx", false);
xmlhttp.send();

//do something with the result
alert(xmlhttp.responseXML.text);
```

See the [XMLHttpRequest Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details